# Android Studio 3.1 Logcat Tool Window to display timestamp in every row

Tags: android, android-studio, logging, logcat

I've used Android Studio's built-in Logcat tool window for a long time.

```
View > Tool Windows > Logcat
```

Recently (as of 3.0 or 3.1?) Android Studio started leaving out timestamps on some of the rows. If multiple rows have the same time stamp, only the first row is shown including a stamp.

Here an example with 5 (not 3) individual logs:

```
06-07 12:10:18.779 D/MainActivity: displaying topX-13 - seen: 1
06-07 12:10:21.230 D/CustomSpinner: constructor 3 called, attrs.getAttributeCount(): 7
    attrs: id - @2131230782
06-07 12:10:21.231 D/CustomSpinner: attrs: background - @17170445
    attrs: padding - 10.0dip
```

It makes it a lot harder to read - at least for me.

I know how to give each row a time stamp in the terminal:

```
adb logcat -v time
```

but how to make it work in the tool window?